# jQuery - pass array of functions to ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new with jQuery, and I'm trying to call two functions on successful ajax (since the documentation says as of 1.5 success callback can take an array of functions).

If I do this, everything works fine:

```
$.ajax({
    url : sJSONFilePath,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : foo(data)
});
```

What do I need to do to pass in an array of functions? If I try the following, I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error in the console:

```
$.ajax({
    url : sJSONFilePath,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : [foo(data), bar(data)]
});
```

I was unable to find any examples of this feature being used. Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is dumb.

Comment: Unless `foo` returns a function, then this `success : foo(data)` doesn't work as well as you may think. You're invoking `foo` immediately instead of passing it as a callback.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no need for an array, you can use the deferred syntax that was also introduced in jQuery 1.5:

```
$.ajax(...).done(foo).done(bar);
```

This is generally cleaner and much more extensible than passing callback functions as parameters to `$.ajax` and relatives.

From the [`$.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

> The jqXHR objects returned by `$.ajax()` as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more information). For convenience and consistency with the callback names used by `$.ajax()`, jqXHR also provides `.error()`, `.success()`, and `.complete()` methods. These methods take a function argument that is called when the `$.ajax()` request terminates, and the **function receives the same arguments as the correspondingly-named** `$.ajax()` **callback**. This **allows you to assign multiple callbacks on a single request**, and **even to assign callbacks after the request may have completed**. (If the request is already complete, the callback is fired immediately.)

[but see the paragraph after, where it explains how `.success`, `.error` and `.complete` are now deprecated and replaced with `.done`, `.fail` and `.always`]

Comment: This works. Does $.done pass (data, textStatus, jqXHR) to foo and bar just like success does? I don't know much about Deferred

Comment: @MJS yes, it does - I'll add some text.

Comment: Just a note for anyone happening upon this:  The documentation appears to suggest that the callbacks are executed in serial.

Comment: @KevinDice of course - they can't possibly be executed in parallel

Comment: I mean synchronously rather than async.

Answer (score 5):

What you do is this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : sJSONFilePath,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data) {
        foo(data);
        bar(data);
    }
});
```

or this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : sJSONFilePath,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : [foo, bar]
});
```

Note that in the second one, I'm not *calling* `foo` and `bar`, I'm listing the function references in an array (since as you say, as of 1.5 jQuery's ajax callback options allow that).

---

You've said that this works fine:

```
$.ajax({
    url : sJSONFilePath,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : foo(data)
});
```

but it doesn't. What that does is immediately **call** the `foo` function, and then assign the return value of that function to the `success` property of the options you're passing to `ajax`. Unless you're using `foo` to build and return a function to use as the callback, that's not what you want to do.

It's important to understand the difference between *calling* a function and using a reference to it. If you have parens after the function name (with or without arguments in them), you're *calling* it. If you just have the name, you're referring to it. E.g.:

```
var f = foo(); // CALLs `foo` and assigns return value to `f`
var f = foo;   // Assigns a reference to `foo` to `f`
```

Comment: This is perfect. I think my JS was cached, and that's why it worked with my borked code. I'll mark this as answer after 15 mins. Thanks for the thorough reply!

Comment: @amnotiam except for completely missing out usage of deferred object syntax, which is now the preferred way to do AJAX callbacks...

Comment: @Alnitak: Fair point, though I'd consider deferreds to be *alternate* instead of *preferred*

Comment: @amnotiam well, _I_ prefer it - I've used both and I'd never to back to the old way now ;-)

Comment: While this post was very informative and answered my question exactly (much, much appreciation), I ended up using the .done() solution above. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: @MJS: Glad that helped! Yes, the new(ish) "promise" mechanism can do it as well, as long as you're on v1.5 or higher. Happy coding,

Answer (score 1):

when writing

```
success : [foo(data), bar(data)]
```

you are in fact evaluating the foo and bar functions (probably with a null argument)

you need to write

```
success : [foo, bar]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call one function that calls the other two:

```
$.ajax({
    url : sJSONFilePath,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : foo_bar(data)
});

function foo_bar(data)
{
   foo(data);
   bar(data);
{
```